# DAG does not execute but it is in the list_dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running an airflow in container inside codebuild, currently it executes everything but in the part to trigger the DAG it fail.

```
      - sudo sh scripts/setup.sh
      - pipenv --three install
      - airflow initdb
      - airflow scheduler > ~/scheduler.log 2>&1 &
      - airflow list_dags -sd $(pwd)/dags
      - airflow trigger_dag -sd $(pwd)/dags Pampa
```

And when i use the list_dags it shows

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Pampa
```

But it does not execute the DAG.

`airflow trigger_dag -sd $(pwd)/dags Pampa`

```
[2018-07-05 20:04:36,495] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor 
[2018-07-05 20:04:36,556] {models.py:189} INFO -
Filling up the DagBag from /codebuild/output/src188373663/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow",
line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 199,
in trigger_dag
    execution_date=args.exec_date)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py",
line 27, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=execution_date)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py",
line 27, in trigger_dag
    raise AirflowException("Dag id {} not found".format(dag_id)) airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Dag id Pampa not found
```

Comment: Hey Carlos - can you add your DAG args to your post?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the $AIRFLOW_HOME it was taking the path of a folder below:

$AIRFLOW_HOME /home/ubuntu

But the dags was in /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/ so it can not find the dags, it just can find the dags when I specify the -sd and the subfolder path in the list_dags.

I have to change the way I have the $AIRFLOW_HOME.